# Can't get FB.getLoginStatus to run

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

EDIT: It turns out I am not very intelligent. I should have checked first thing if my partner changed the settings of the FB app... which he did. I think he actually mentioned it to me as well. Ah, the importance of communication. Sorry to the people who answered my question.

Here's the code I have. The following will print out the BALH and the BALefefH but not "response". There's no error on the console.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("BALH");
        var myID;
        var access_token;

   FB.init({
           appId  : NUMBER,
            status : true,
            cookie : true,
            xfbml  : true,
   });
   console.log("BALefefH");

   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
           console.log("response");
           if(!response.session) {
               FB.login(function(response) {
                       myId = response.session.uid;
                       access_token = response.session.access_token;
                       beginStuff(myId, access_token);
                       if (!response.session) {
                           console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                       }
                   });
           }
           else if(response.session) {
               myId = response.session.uid;
               access_token = response.session.access_token;
               beginStuff(myId, access_token);
           }
   });

});
```

Comment: A link to a sample would help make the issue much clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you loading the sdk asynchronously? If you are loading it asynchronously, you should put all calls to FB within a window.fbAsyncInit function. This is called once the sdk has finished loading and will ensure that FB is defined.

Also make sure if you aren't loading asynchronously that you are loading it before this script runs. So if you are including both the fb js sdk and your snippet above, make sure the fb js sdk is first.